# Trying to detect the point of overlapping colours in a Videocapture

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, hsv

[enter image description here][1]Im working on a project where im trying to trace a white line passing from yellow to green colour, once the line has been passed I want Perfect to be printed just once at the point in which it crosses I've written this code but it doesn't quite work.

I've tried adding a pixel counter to detect a change of pixel colour from the last seen frame but to no avail

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

# Specifying upper and lower ranges of color to detect in hsv format
lower = np.array([35, 100, 140])
upper = np.array([70, 255, 255]) # (These ranges will detect Yellow)

# Capturing webcam footage
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

prev_count = 0
curr_count = 0
frame_count = 0
perfect_printed = False
last_perfect_time = 0

while True:
    success, video = cap.read() # Reading webcam footage

    img = cv2.cvtColor(video, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) # Converting BGR image to HSV format

    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper) # Masking the image to find our color

    mask_contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # Finding contours in mask image

    # Finding position of all contours
    if len(mask_contours) != 0:
        for mask_contour in mask_contours:
            area = cv2.contourArea(mask_contour)
            if area > 5 and area < 30:
                x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(mask_contour)
                cv2.rectangle(video, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 1) #drawing rectangle
                curr_count += area

    cv2.imshow("mask image", mask) # Displaying mask image

    cv2.imshow("window", video) # Displaying webcam image

    # Check if the pixel count has decreased by more than 10 in 2 frames
    if frame_count == 1:
        if (prev_count - curr_count) > 9 and not perfect_printed and time.time() - last_perfect_time > 2:
            print("Perfect")
            cv2.imwrite('perfect_screenshot.jpg', video)
            perfect_printed = True
            last_perfect_time = time.time()
        prev_count = curr_count
        curr_count = 0
        frame_count = 0
    else:
        frame_count += 1

    # Reset perfect_printed if it has been printed before
    if perfect_printed:
        perfect_printed = False

    # Wait for user to press Esc key to close the window
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Image 1 https://i.gyazo.com/86dc470ddd18b901b0bf8bb7c578c87e.png

to

Image 2 https://gyazo.com/5ea703eed44156bb12e35962d3a04fc6

Comment: What's your question? Where's "this code" you supposedly wrote but that "doesn't quite work"? What sort of response are you expecting to get to this post -- in its current state, I don't see anything actionable. [ask]

Comment: Hi, I'm new to this I tried posting my code but wasn't familiar with in Ctrl+K indentation, I've added the code.

Comment: The gradient is always horizontal, as it appears to be in those illustrations? The line is always perfectly vertical? (i.e. assuming no artifacts caused by lossy compression, all the rows should be the same?) | The input is a sequence of frames where the gradient background is constant and unmoving? And the white line is moving only in single direction? Please elaborate. | It would be useful if you could provide pristine input images (without the drawing on them). Even better, a short sample input video. | "it doesn't quite work" -- what exactly does that mean?